# Iptables: Does it make sense to use --source flag in OUTPUT?

Tags: iptables

Suppose I have a router with at least 2 interfaces, `192.168.10.254` and `192.168.20.254`, linked to two different networks with 24 bits masks.

Would the following iptables command be any different if we removed the `-s = --source`) flag?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

It is my understanding that the routeur will always use its `192.168.10.254` interface to ping the `192.168.10.0/24` network, so I see the `-s` flag as completely useless and misleading. Yet it is accepted by iptables in the OUTPUT cases, so I must be missing something?

Comment: `ping -I 192.168.20.254 192.168.10.2`

Answer (score 1):

With sufficient previliges a process on your system could craft TCP/IP packets with bogus sender addresses. This is common with DOS attacks for example.

Other than that your system could have multiple valid source addresses.

Implementing a rule (as in not allowing source in OUTPUT) , seems to go beyond the scope of what iptables should do.